# Compare two geojson file in order to know which sections are in common

Tags: python, geojson

I'm knew in the field of working with geospatial data in python.
I have two files:

- A reference geojson file that contains every bike path in a city
- A LineString geojson of a bike route between an origin and destination in the same city

What I would like to do is compare those to files to know which section in my bike route is a bike path in order to calculate the global % of my route that is on a bike path. If anyone knows if it is possible and with which python module/method please let me know ! It would really help me.

For the moment I only have researched documentation, I know you can easily read a geojson file in python but  didn't find anything to compare two geojson object without using a map.

For the moment I have succeeded to overlay both data but I don't really know what to do with it...

1. First I load my bike route data :

```py
with open(file_path, encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
route = pd\
            .json_normalize(data['journeys'], record_path=['sections', 'geojson', 'coordinates'])\
            .rename(columns={0: 'x', 1: 'y'})

route['index'] = 3

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(route, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(route.x, route.y), crs = "EPSG:4326") # type: ignore
route = gdf.groupby(['index'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x:  LineString(x.tolist()))
route = gpd.GeoDataFrame(route, geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326") # type: ignore
route.reset_index(inplace=True)
route.plot(column='index')
```

[image: Result]

2. Then a load my reference file (every bike path in Paris)

```py
with open(ref_path, encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

ref = pd.json_normalize(data)[['objectid', 'num_pave', 'lib_level', 'lib_classe', 'geo_shape.geometry.coordinates']]
#ref = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ref) # type: ignore
ref = ref.dropna()
ref = ref.explode('geo_shape.geometry.coordinates').explode('geo_shape.geometry.coordinates').reset_index()
ref['x'] = ref['geo_shape.geometry.coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
ref['y'] = ref['geo_shape.geometry.coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[1])

ref['type'] = ref['x'].apply(lambda x: 1 if type(x) == list else 0)
ref.loc[ref['type'] == 1, 'x'] = ref.loc[ref['type'] == 1, 'x'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
ref.loc[ref['type'] == 1, 'y'] = ref.loc[ref['type'] == 1, 'y'].apply(lambda x: x[1])

ref = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ref, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(ref['x'], ref['y']), crs = "EPSG:4326") # type: ignore
ref = ref.groupby(['objectid'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x:  LineString(x.tolist()))
ref = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ref, geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326") # type: ignore
ref.reset_index(inplace=True)
ref.plot(column='objectid')
```

[image: 2nd Result]

3. Then I use the overlay method, which gives me Multipoint result. I dont know what to do next to compute the length of the initial route bike overlaying the reference bike paths...

```py
gpd.overlay(route, ref, how = 'intersection', keep_geom_type = False)

>>>  index  objectid                                           geometry
0       3       133    MULTIPOINT (2.38773 48.84134, 2.38793 48.84129)
1       3       136    MULTIPOINT (2.38804 48.84127, 2.38799 48.84128)
2       3       218    MULTIPOINT (2.39365 48.84099, 2.39378 48.84100)
3       3       219    MULTIPOINT (2.39282 48.84095, 2.39284 48.84095)
4       3       238    MULTIPOINT (2.39293 48.84095, 2.39365 48.84099)
5       3       239    MULTIPOINT (2.38748 48.84140, 2.38768 48.84135)
6       3      6499    MULTIPOINT (2.38531 48.84242, 2.38549 48.84233)
7       3      6502    MULTIPOINT (2.38644 48.84187, 2.38626 48.84195)
8       3      7419    MULTIPOINT (2.38512 48.84250, 2.38527 48.84243)
9       3      8376    MULTIPOINT (2.41299 48.84248, 2.41300 48.84246)
10      3      8495    MULTIPOINT (2.40460 48.84080, 2.40245 48.84102)
11      3      8749    MULTIPOINT (2.41300 48.84242, 2.41307 48.84199)
12      3      8943    MULTIPOINT (2.40062 48.84101, 2.40065 48.84101)
13      3      9138  MULTIPOINT (2.41336 48.84176, 2.41335 48.84142...
14      3      9150    MULTIPOINT (2.41308 48.84188, 2.41308 48.84189)
15      3      9415    MULTIPOINT (2.40895 48.84059, 2.40893 48.84059)
16      3      9417    MULTIPOINT (2.40571 48.84075, 2.40609 48.84072)
17      3      9491    MULTIPOINT (2.40755 48.84058, 2.40763 48.84057)
18      3      9492    MULTIPOINT (2.40493 48.84077, 2.40571 48.84075)
19      3      9500    MULTIPOINT (2.40656 48.84068, 2.40618 48.84071)
20      3      9871    MULTIPOINT (2.40473 48.84079, 2.40493 48.84077)
21      3     10200    MULTIPOINT (2.40656 48.84068, 2.40716 48.84062)
22      3     10278    MULTIPOINT (2.40930 48.84059, 2.40932 48.84059)
23      3     10681    MULTIPOINT (2.40240 48.84100, 2.40245 48.84102)
...
38      3     18281    MULTIPOINT (2.38431 48.84289, 2.38477 48.84267)
39      3     18283    MULTIPOINT (2.38304 48.84350, 2.38312 48.84346)
40      3     18708    MULTIPOINT (2.38403 48.84302, 2.38412 48.84298)
41      3     18716    MULTIPOINT (2.38423 48.84293, 2.38417 48.84296)
```

If I plot it, it gives me this: [image: 3rd result]

Comment: Do you have the entire route of the bike ride showing every road used, or just the start and end points? If the latter than I can't imagine there is any way to find out if a ride used a bike lane or not

Comment: I have the entire route of the bike ride, with every road used

Comment: I’ve updated my post with what I achieved so far, hope that helps